# Paper definition for Brother QL-570 labels

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, printers, printer-control-language

I'm developing a webapp where I want to enable the user to print directly to the label printer (Brother QL-570). The label will contain a barcode and some text, and to achieve this I'm currently examining jsprintsetup Firefox addon.

I've been able to set the printer correctly, but I've failed setting the paper definition for Brother's Small Address Label (62x29 mm), and I cannot figure out how to find the proper way to set this up.

My script is looking like this at the moment:

```
jsPrintSetup.setPrinter('Brother QL-570 LE');
jsPrintSetup.setOption('orientation', jsPrintSetup.kPortraitOrientation);
jsPrintSetup.definePaperSize(200, 200, 'XX', 'XX','Small Address Label', 62, 29, 1); 
jsPrintSetup.setPaperSizeData(200);
```

But I'm stuck. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: i printed label with JS without an addon by setting the printer defaults to the label size paper. i didn't have a barcode though, just text. still, if you can set the defaults in the OS, you might not need to customize it in JS.